# proper use of commitData in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

My base problem is that I cannot get self.commitData.emit() to work in PyQt5 where as it worked on PyQt4. self refers to my subclass of

QItemDelegate and self.commitData.emit(editor) raises an error:

> self.commitData.emit(editor) AttributeError: signal was not defined in
>   the first super-class of #class 'filterDelegate'

Portions of my subclass to QItemDelegate are shown below:

custom delegate:

```
class filterDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(filterDelegate,self).__init__(parent)
        self.parameterlist=parent.parameterlist
        self.parent=parent

    def dataCommit(self):
        index=self.mindex
        model=index.model()
        editor=self.sender()
        lastrow=model.rowCount()-1              
        if isinstance(editor,(QComboBox)):
            self.commitData.emit(editor)
            self.closeEditor.emit(editor,QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)
```

The errors occur at the line containing self.commitData.emit(editor) and
PyCharm shows self.commitData.emit as not having attribute emit.
Moreover substitution of QItemDelegate.commitData.emit(editor) for self.commitData.emit(editor) above gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute
>   'emit' Which is likely the same error seen earlier.

The thing that's strange is that all this worked for PyQt4 but not PyQt5.

Any ideas on how to emit the commitData signal for PyQt5 are most welcome and I could not find the answer after an hour on Google.

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: You can show where to make the connection to the slot: `dataCommit`

Comment: In addition you could share the complete code of your `QItemDelegate` to be able to test it.